# matlab: how to color-code a volumetric isosurface plot based on the gradient of the isosurface

Tags: matlab, visualization, data-visualization, matlab-figure

Is it possible to color-code a volumetric isosurface plot based on the gradient of the isosurface in matlab? For example, based on something that uses the following code to generate the isosurface:

```
fv = isosurface(V,200);
p2 = patch(fv,'FaceColor','red');
isonormals(V,p2)
view(3)
daspect([1 1 1])
axis tight
```

EDIT: As pointed out in the comments: is there a way of computing the gradient of an arbitrary triangular surface and use it to color-code a surface?

Comment: can you give us some example data? what is `V`?

Comment: The question really is how to compute the gradient of an arbitrary triangular surface, I hope. If that is the case, modify the question to be clearer, else the answer is `patch(fv,'FaceColor',computedGradient);`

Comment: @AnderBiguri Actually it would be `..., 'FaceColor', 'flat' (or interp), 'CData', computedGradient)`

Comment: @Suever you are rigth, but I am 99.99% sure that he is not asking about that.... :P

Comment: @AnderBirguri thanks for the suggestion. you are right